# Update a DateTimes's Time, but not the date

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
MyTable:
 id     int
 Date1  DateTime
 Date2  DateTime
```

How can I set the time of Date2 to be the same as Date1 without affecting the date of Date2?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: sql 2008 r2. I'd be interested to know what doesn't work in the different versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update `Date2` with only the difference in days between the two dates.

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET Date2 = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, Date1, Date2), Date1);
```

This will preserve the date portion of `Date2`.

**UPDATE:** This method essentially reconstructs `Date2` by using `Date1` as a reference and only adding the difference in days between `Date1` and `Date2` - preserving the TimeStamp from `Date1`.

Comment: I fear you misunderstood the question, the date of date2 should remain the same

Comment: Lol, I understood the question. I've rephrased my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This works from sql server 2008+

```
select cast(cast(date2 as date) as datetime) + cast(date1 as time) newdate2
from (select getdate() date2, cast('2012-01-01 20:00' as datetime) date1) a
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @Date2)) + DATEADD(day, -datediff(day, 0, @Date1), @Date1)
```